# How does input here get a .value and what is a ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

How does input here get a `.value`? Is it some how getting this from a node in:

`<input ref={node => {
     input = node
 }} />`

Is `node` the DOM node, as in the input tag?

What exactly is a `ref` anyway and why do we need it to get the input value?

Can I put `ref` on any html type tag in react to get the DOM node?

```js
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodo } from '../actions'

let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
  let input

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (!input.value.trim()) {
          return
        }
        dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
        input.value = ''
      }}>
        <input ref={node => {
          input = node
        }} />
        <button type="submit">
          Add Todo
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
AddTodo = connect()(AddTodo)

export default AddTodo
```

Comment: Have you tried to read official React documentation about `ref` explaining how it works? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: interesting, would this implementation be better or worse that using state to save the input and set onChange? How could you determine which is better?

Comment: In order to answer your question I would suggest you to read another great link https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html. . As a short answer, you should use `ref` as least as possible in your React code. If you can avoid it, then avoid it.

Comment: ref is basically great if you're doing some form of templating and only want to refer to the element that's part of said encapsulating component. Otherwise the alternative would be to use a whole heap of ids which may or may not be bad, but it largely depends on how you want the whole thing to be interacting with each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. when ref with a [Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-class-component) then the node is an instance of Component,when ref an [Element](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element) then the node is an DOMElement instance.
2. you can the `ref` anywhere,but the react suggest [don't to overuse](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs).
3. you have two ways to use ref. [ref with function](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-functional-components) & [ref as attribute with string name](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs).
4. react provide [`value`/`check`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) to retrieve the form elements value.